# Setting up an Android Emulator's camera to mirror the emulator's own window

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I'm basically looking to set the Android Emulator's camera (could be Genymotion emulator as well) to its own window, so that I could, for instance, stream my own screen through livestream services.

That shouldn't be too hack together, right? But I can't seem to figure out the program needed to create a video stream and set it up as an input to the Android Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my main use was to show my own phone's screen through Instagram's live stories and I achieved it using CamTwist:

1. I plugged my iPhone to my macbook
2. Downloaded CamTwist
3. Used the following configurations:

[image: CamTwist screenshot]
The rotation and zoom were needed to make the image fit the android emulator's webcam viewport

4. Having set the camtwist to my new Setup, I'll open up the CamTwist preferences and set my **Video Size** to 1280x720
5. Restart CamTwist so your settings stick and then open up the Studio, cut to your Setup
6. Open up the Android Virtual Device manager
7. Edit your emulator's settings
8. Open advanced settings
9. Set both the front and back cameras to Webcam0
10. Voila, you can now use your CamTwist stream on any livestream services, Periscope, Snapchat, Instagram, you name it. ‍♂️